# Apache logs: "::1 ... "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -

Tags: apache, apache2, ip-address, http, logging

Just looking at logs of a not-so-busy site on one of our Apache servers and notice tons of these in the log:

```
::1 - - [15/Apr/2011:12:11:40 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Apr/2011:12:11:41 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Apr/2011:12:11:44 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

They seem to appear multiple times just below the GET requests where Apache has served a page & its related images.

1. what do they mean?
2. what IP is "`::1`"?
3. if they're benign can I suppress them?

Comment: Related, see [Ignore “HTTP 1.0 OPTIONS” request in GoAccess](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/100687) web analysis.

Answer (score 7):

From [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/apache-load-99241.html)

> It's Apache polling its child
>   processes to verify they're responding
>   correctly.
>
> 31-2 - 0/0/44 . 0.00 41 0 0.0 0.00
>   0.92 ::1 mxx1.xx.com OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
>
> The second field, " - ", shows that
>   this isn't an active connection.. It's
>   the last connection that took place
>   for this particular thread/process.
>   Since Apache polls its children every
>   few minutes it's not unusual to see
>   many of these on a system with light
>   web traffic.
>
> With some versions of Apache you'd see
>   a "GET /" instead of "OPTIONS *" for
>   these connections.
>
> https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41796

Comment: I see. So, given what you quoted, I guess I could see the value in logging an *error* when a child process was polled...but as it stands these log entries seem pretty useless. **Does anyone know how to suppress them?**

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your second question: `::1` is `localhost` in ipv6.
Regarding your third question:

```
# Mark requests for the robots.txt file
SetEnvIf Request_Method "^OPTIONS$" dontlog
# Log what remains
CustomLog logs/custom.log common env=!dontlog
```

see also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog

Answer (score 1):

Check your servers /etc/hosts file.  You probably have the entry for 'localhost' set to '::1' which is IPV6 format.  Change it to '127.0.0.1' (IPV4) and this log message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

i had this 'problem' and it was annoying as hell. one of two servers i have did this.
a year or two later... i just discovered that on one server i has listen 443 in the httpd.conf.

so i put the 'Listen 443' directive in the ssl.conf file.

apachectl graceful

poof... annoying problem gone.