# Ignore "HTTP 1.0 OPTIONS" request in GoAccess?

Tags: apache, analytics

We are analyzing website access with [GoAccess web log analyzer](https://goaccess.io/). Here's what we see under ***Requested Files (URLs)***:

```
> 2 - Requested Files (URLs)                                 Total: 366/66721

 Hits  Vis.     %   Bandwidth Mtd     Proto    Data
 ----- ---- ----- ----------- ------- -------- ----
 16884    9 8.24%     0.0   B OPTIONS HTTP/1.0 *
 5342  3584 2.61%  100.59 MiB GET     HTTP/1.1 /
 2821  2166 1.38%    8.41 MiB GET     HTTP/1.1 /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&m
 2692  2050 1.31%   48.36 MiB GET     HTTP/1.1 /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&m
 1990  1824 0.97%   96.18 MiB GET     HTTP/1.1 /w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&m
 ...
```

[Apache's polling of child processes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/12305) is skewing the results of the analysis. Its also skewing the ***Visitor Hostname IPs***, ***Operating Systems***, ***Browsers***, etc.

How do we tell GoAccess to ignore the Apache polls?

Answer (score 1):

You can run GoAccess with `-e`, for example:

```
goaccess -f /var/log/apache2/access.log -e ::1
```